# Paraphrasing the quote "independent of nationalism and disintegration."

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

" independent of nationalism and disintegration."

Kicking off the polling in a pre-recorded statement, Crimean Prime Minister Sergey Aksyonov called on the residents of Crimea to cast their vote "independent of nationalism and disintegration."

I know the meanings of nationalism and disitegration but in this phrase I cannot understand them. My intuition is that people are expected to vote in the referundom without thinking about nationalism and disintegration!!!!  I am really confused. Which nationalism ? Nationalism related to Ukraine or Crimea? Which disintegration? From Russia or Ukraine?

I would be greatful if you replace the words " independent of " and " nationalism" and " disintegration" with another words.

Comment: An Answerer reports that this is a mistranslation.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this guy's quote in Russian. You read a wrong translation. He actually said "regardless of your nationality/ethnicity and religion/creed." I gave two synonyms for every term.

Comment: +1 Wow! How did the translator get from "religion" to "disintegration"? Are there two similar words in Russian, or can the word he used also mean "sect" or "religious division"?

Comment: @StoneyB: The article might have been written by someone who speaks English but not Russian. He needed the quote and translated it in some sloppy software. That word just means 'the religion that you follow.' It is not normally used for 'sect' or 'religious division.'